# Improperly Formatted If Statements in Java

Tags: java, if-statement

when you have improperly formatted if statements, how do you know which if statements go where?

So, if you had multi-lined if statements, and you removed all of the spaces and curly brackets (so that everything is aligned left) . . .

Are there rules that state where the if statements go?

Comment: The indentation of the code has nothing to do with its execution, in **Java**.

Comment: Everything within `{}` is for one statement (block)...

Comment: For multilined if statements you have to use curly brackets. If you don't use curly brackets the if statement is only regarding the next line. Indention doesn't affect functionality, but you should indent it properly so it's easily readable.

Comment: @user3284549 Ok, but in this case [link](http://imgur.com/CINowYV), how would I know where the if statements go?

Comment: Either put beloning statements on the right side of the if statement, or indent lines that belong to the if statement to the right (most probably prefer the latter)

Answer (score 0):

That is defined in the Java Language Specification (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9)

Basically it is `if (expression) statement` or `if (expression) statement else statement` with some special cases so that an `else` always belongs to the immediate preceeding `if`.

So in your example the `else` on line 12 belongs to the `if` on line 11.